# Simplifying event with a Lambda method doesn't work in Java

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I am trying to provide a simpler version of an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` in Java 8 with JavaFX.

The final version is supposed to look like

```
package dialogutil;

import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Clickable extends EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    public static Clickable EMPTY = () -> {};

    public void onClick();

    @Override
    public default void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        this.onClick();
        if (event != null && event.getSource() != null) {
            ((Dialog)event.getSource()).hide();
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I am trying to create event handlers in a simpler way: they don't take the event as a parameter, and they care about hiding themselves.

For the sake of demonstration, I created a test suite to reproduce the problem I have with that:

```
package test;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

import org.junit.Test;

public class BastelTest {

    /**
     * Interface Complicated is called with a value.
     */
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Complicated {
        void complicated(int value);
    }


    /**
     * Interface Simple is called without a value.
     */
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Simple extends Complicated {
        void simple();
        /**
         * The value given is printed and then the call is deflected to the simple method given.
         */
        @Override
        default void complicated(int value) {
            System.out.println("Swallowing the " + value);
            simple();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is in order to try the Complicated/Simple interface.
     * The given {@link Complicated} is called with a 42.
     * It can be a {@link Simple} as well; in this case the call is deflected.
     * @param x
     */
    private void callIt(Complicated x) {
        x.complicated(42);
    }

    /**
     * This is the interface I am indeed working on.
     * Here the deflection doesn't work; instead, I get an AbstractMethodError.
     */
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Clickable extends EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        public static Clickable EMPTY = () -> {};

        public void onClick();

        @Override
        public default void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Simplifying the call:");
            this.onClick();
            System.out.println("Call simplified.");
        }

    }

    private void handle(EventHandler<ActionEvent> x) {
        System.out.println("Handling null event via " + x);
        x.handle(null);
        System.out.println("Handling nonnull event via " + x);
        x.handle(new ActionEvent());
    }


    @Test
    public void testFunc() {
        callIt(x -> System.out.println("Complicated with " + x));
        callIt((Simple) () -> System.out.println("Called simple."));

        Clickable c = () -> System.out.println("Hdl3");
        c.handle(null);

        handle(x -> System.out.println("Hdl1 " + x));
        handle((Clickable)() -> System.out.println("Hdl2"));
        handle(Clickable.EMPTY);
    }
}
```

Here I expect the following to happen:

- If I call `callIt()` or `handle()` with the base version of the handler, it is called as usual.
- If I call them with the "specialized", simplified version of the handler class, I expect it to deflect that call to the simplified version I give.

This works only partially:

- with the `Simple`/`Complicated` combination, it works: calling the `complicated(int)` method of a `Simple` prints the given argument and then calls the `simple()` method, which is in turn expressed as a lambda.
- The combination I am after, however, is expressing an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` as a lambda (possibly even empty) which forms a `Clickable` whose `handle()` calls this `onClick()`. (Please don't be confused about the names; it is a quite historic interface which I am just going to improve, but not completely change.) In this case, it doesn't work.

Here is the stack trace I get:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method test/BastelTest$$Lambda$7.handle(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V is abstract
    at test.BastelTest$$Lambda$7/25282035.handle(Unknown Source)
    at test.BastelTest.handle(BastelTest.java:38)
    at test.BastelTest.testFunc(BastelTest.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at [usual test case stuff...]
```

Why doesn't it work?

(If I am not clear enough about the situation, please tell me that.)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with JDK 1.8.0_74. What version do you have? Also, this is unrelated but `interface Simple extends Complicated` looks really weird (if something is simple then it is complicated?)

Comment: Unrelated. `public static Clickable.EMPTY` - variables in `interface`s are not allowed, `EMPTY` is implicitly `public static final`. `public void onClick()` here `public` is redundant.

Comment: I have 1.8.0_20. Good idea - I should update in order to see if it works then...

Comment: @Tunaki If something has a simple interface, it can as well have a complicated interface. Not the best wording, but it works :-)

Comment: @glglgl No, because in this code *every* `Simple` is also `Complicated`, which makes no sense.

Comment: @James_D As said, the wording is not the best, but it is an example. I should have named them `HasSimpleInterface` and `HasComplicatedInterface`.

Comment: Can’t reproduce even with `1.8.0_20`. Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Note that the line numbers of your stack trace do not match the code of the test suite. Having mismatched classes can be the cause of such errors.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have checked that everything has been compiled like with a clean build? As said, the line numbers of your posted stack trace do not match the posted code. I also tried your posted code with Eclipse without problems, but you might be using a different version…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn’t be able to provoke an `AbstractMethodError` (or any kind of `LinkageError`) using ordinary Java operations. So encountering it is usually a sign of either, a broken compiler or an incompatibly changed environment, i.e. a class is linked against a different version of a class than it saw at compile-time.

What we see here, is a missing *bridge method* in an `interface`. When a generic type is extended by either, a reifiable type or a type redeclaring a type variable using a different lower bound, the raw type signature of inherited methods may change and require a bridge method having the old raw signature and delegating to the method with the new signature.

In your code, the reifiable type `Clickable` extends the generic type `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` and has two methods at the byte code level, `void handle(ActionEvent)` and `void handle(Event)`, the latter requiring a bridge method delegating to the former.

Starting with Java 8, these bridge method are implemented in the `interface` (as now non-`abstract` methods are possible), removing the burden of implementing it from all implementation classes (greatly simplifying the process of generating classes for lambda expressions).

From the stack trace we can see that the method `BastelTest.handle` is trying to invoke the `handle` method on an instance with the compile-time type `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` which will end up at the raw method `handle(Ljavafx/event/Event;)V`, but the required bridge method is missing for the lambda instance, which implies that it is also missing in the interface from which it should be inherited.

For a test suite like yours, where all linked classes are nested classes and therefore compiled together, it’s unlikely to get mismatched versions (though not impossible). The other possibility is that you are using an older Eclipse version bearing the [bug 436350, “Missing bridge method in interface results in AbstractMethodError”](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436350).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! While I have now moved away towards a) using a slightly different approach and b) working on other spots in the code, I really appreciate this very extensive answer. Due to time restrictions, I currently cannot test if Eclipse is "guilty", but I'll look at it as soon as I can - probably next week.